# Footer at the bottom of page, if wrapper is absolute positioned

Tags: html, css, footer

I have such html structure:

```
<body>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>  
      ****
  </div> 
  <div class='footer'>
  </div> 
</body>
```

and such css:

```
body, html{
  background-color: #5669e1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10010;
  width:100%;
  height: 226px;
  background: url(../images/header.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;  
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -600px;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding-bottom: 176px;  
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.footer{
  height: 176px;
  background: url(../images/footer.png) no-repeat center;
  position: relative;  
  height: 176px;  
  margin-top: -176px;  
}
```

but it is after header, when my wrapper was not absolute it was displayed strange on different pages too. How can i put it on bottom, in 176px of wrapper?

Comment: Try to add `position:absolute` and `bottom:0;` to your footer. And don't forget to set width for your footer

Comment: @Roman no, same as Scott Rowell solution do: i see this: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/footer_trouble1.jpg

Comment: Sorry, saw the answer too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.header {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}

.footer {
    height: 176px;
}



<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p>header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i try this before, i see this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/footer_trouble1.jpg

Comment: I think that's happening because your wrapper class is set to position:absolute;. That basically makes it so height is ignored by other divs. Try removing it.

Comment: removing what? div which i need 200% ) & ?

Comment: removing position:absolute from your .wrapper class, if at all possible. I'm not sure how it'll affect your page! But that's the reason your footer is stuck at that position instead of the bottom of the page.

Comment: i understand, but i can't do this, it will affect header

Comment: That's what I feared. I don't see much of a point of having your .header class having position:relative;. So maybe if you remove position:relative; from header, and position:absolute; from wrapper it could solve your problem. I'll update my post for you with my code.